# Scorer not recognizing inputs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to utilize a custom scorer with the following code

```
def edge_score(y, y_pred):
    y_pred.name = 'y_pred'
    y.name = 'y'

    df = pd.concat([y_pred, y])

    df['sign_pred'] = df.y_pred.apply(np.sign)
    df['sign_true'] = df.y.apply(np.sign)
    df['is_correct'] = 0
    df.loc[
        df.sign_pred * df.sign_true > 0, 'is_correct'] = 1
    df['is_incorrect'] = 0
    df.loc[
        df.sign_pred * df.sign_true < 0, 'is_incorrect'] = 1
    df['is_predicted'] = df.is_correct + df.is_incorrect
    df['result'] = df.sign_pred * df.y
    df['edge'] = df.result.mean()
    output_errors = df[['edge']]
    output_errors.to_numpy()

    return np.average(output_errors)
edge = make_scorer(edge_score)
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'
```

When I comment out the .name lines, I get the following error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

When I convert true and predictions to dataframe, I get the following error

```
y_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred)
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
```

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'y_pred'
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def custom_score(y_true, y_pred):
  true_sign = np.sign(y_true)
  pred_sign = np.sign(y_pred)
  true_vs_pred = np.where(true_sign == pred_sign, 1, 0)
  true_pred = (true_vs_pred == 1).sum()
  return true_pred
custom_scorer = make_scorer(custom_score, greater_is_better=True)
```

convert everything to an array and then process that.

Answer (score 2):

You should first create a DataFrame with the two numpy arrays `y` and `y_pred`, and then perform all the operations.

```
def edge_score(y, y_pred):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({"y":y,
                       "y_pred":y_pred})

    df['sign_pred'] = df.y_pred.apply(np.sign)
    df['sign_true'] = df.y.apply(np.sign)
    df['is_correct'] = 0
    df.loc[
        df.sign_pred * df.sign_true > 0, 'is_correct'] = 1
    df['is_incorrect'] = 0
    df.loc[
        df.sign_pred * df.sign_true < 0, 'is_incorrect'] = 1
    df['is_predicted'] = df.is_correct + df.is_incorrect
    df['result'] = df.sign_pred * df.y
    df['edge'] = df.result.mean()
    output_errors = df[['edge']]
    output_errors.to_numpy()

    return np.average(output_errors)

edge = make_scorer(edge_score)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines of code

```
    df['sign_pred'] = df.y_pred.apply(np.sign)
    df['sign_true'] = df.y.apply(np.sign)
```

to these:

```
    df['sign_pred'] = np.sign(y_pred)
    df['sign_true'] = np.sign(y)
```

Comment: I run into the following error
```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: @Tomward Remove the two first lines `y_pred.name = 'y_pred'` and `y.name = 'y'` from `edge_score`.

Comment: I get the following error
`
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'y'
`
im starting to think that y and y pred arent getting sent to the scorer at all, even tho I think I formatted it properly

Comment: @desertnaut I wasn't using the indents for code formatting; they were to match the indentation in the OP's function, to help clarify where the code should go :)